# What evaluation classifiers? Precision & recall?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, precision-recall

I have some labeled data which classifies datasets as positive or negative. Now i have an algorithm that does the same automatically and I want to compare the results.

I was said to use precision and recall, but I'm not sure whether those are appropriate because the true negatives don't even appear in the formulas. I'd rather tend to use a general "prediction rate" for both, positives and negatives.

How would be a good way to evaluate the algorithm? Thanks!!

Comment: Can you please post your code?

Comment: the results look like this:
<pre>
data      + user + algorithm
----------|------|----------
some text | pos  |  pos
other txt | neg  |  pos
whatever  | neg  |  neg
littlepny | pos  |  neg
stackover | neg  |  pos</pre>

Comment: sry for the format... i'm new here... the results look like this: {[some text, pos, pos]; [other txt, neg, pos]; [whatever, neg, neg]; [littlepny, pos, neg]} ...so its like some data, then the manual annotation, then the program's output. ...and i'm just not sure if i should use precision/recall to show how good it works or some other "numbers"... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is no general "best" method of evaluation, everything depends on what is your aim, as each method captures different phenomena:

- Accuracy is the simple measure, well suited for multi-label classification and rather well balanced data
- F1-score captures precision/recall tradeoff
- MCC is a good measure which is well suited for dataset with large dissproportion in the class sizes